# I am unable to implement JCanvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, jcanvas

I am new to learn JCanvas. I am trying to implement a simple JCanvas program.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>  
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">             </script>
        <script src='jcanvas.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="drawingCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid  black;align:center;"></canvas>
        <script>
           var canvas = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas");
           var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
           $('canvas').drawArc({
              strokeStyle: 'green',
              draggable: true,
              x:100, y:100,
              radius: 50
           });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I am unable to Implement the above. 
The Circle I am trying to draw here is not getting displayed on the canvas. 
What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is quite fine itself. Consider wrapping your code in `$(document).ready(function () {});`, like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('canvas#drawingCanvas').drawArc({
      strokeStyle: 'green',
      draggable: true,
      x:100, y:100,
      radius: 50
   });
});
</script>
```

This guarantees that your code will executed when the whole DOM structure is loaded in browser memory and ready to interact with JavaScript. See [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more details.

I've also created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmeB4/2/), where your code just works. I attached the jCanvas using URL from [here](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox/), so it might stop working occasionally.

**UPDATE**: removed unused variables from the code, added id to jQuery selector.
**UPDATE2**: Without jsFiddle, it should look like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Sample</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/resources/jcanvas/jcanvas.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('canvas#drawingCanvas').drawArc({
                strokeStyle: 'green',
                draggable: true,
                x:100, y:100,
                radius: 50
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="drawingCanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid  black;align:center;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE3**: Please do not use jCanvas attaching like in the sample above, the link was grabbed from [jCanvas showroom](http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/sandbox/) and is not supposed to be reliable CDN. It might be changed or removed, and it might not be ready to high load.

Comment: See link to jsFiddle in my answer, does it also fail?

Comment: Yeah I tried that code too, it also failed. Everything is okay but cant understand what the problem is?

Comment: Ok, then which browser do you use? For me it works fine in Chrome, Safari and FireFox, but fails in IE11, let me investigate why.

Comment: Consider also checking Chrome developer tools console. To open it on Windows just hit `F12`, switch to console tab inside it and then reload the page. See this https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/ for more details.

Comment: <script src='jcanvas.min.js'></script> is this correct to implement jcanvas?

Comment: @user318826, looks like your `jcanvas.min.js` is missing. Download it and place to corresponding path.  Try also the full HTML which I've just added to the answer, it uses CDN versions of both `jQuery` and `jCanvas`.

Answer (score 0):

there are probably other ways, but this works. I sourced jCanvas and jQuery internally

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>  
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src='jcanvas.min.js'></script>    
    <script>
           var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
           var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
           function init(){
              $("canvas").drawArc({
              strokeStyle: 'green',
              draggable: true,
              x:100, y:100,
              radius: 50
              });
           }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init()">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid  black;align:center;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```